# How to load Html layout into vuejs component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, codeigniter-3

I am using Vuejs cdn. In which I have a Navigation menu. I want to load different layout when a user clicks on Nav menu.

for example

```
<div class="row" id="mytemplate">
<div class="col-sm-3 sidebar-col">
    <div>
      <nav class="settings-sidebar">
        <h4>Profile settings</h4>
        <ul>
            <li class="active" v-on:click="Profile()">
                <a  >Profile picture</a>
            </li>
            <li class="" v-on:click="Business()">
                <a  >Business details</a>
            </li>
            <li class="" v-on:click="Equipments()">
                <a  >Equipments details</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 settings-body">
    {{ load_layout_here }}
</div>
```

Now when user click on "Business Details" option it should run function `Business()` and load layout from business.html or business.php

the sample code in business.php

```
<div class="form">
<div class="input-field">
    <h5>Business name</h5>
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="primary-phone" value="Perfect choice movers" placeholder="Your business name" maxlength="15">
</div>
<div class="input-field inline-input">
    <h5>City</h5>
    <input type="text" class="textbox " name="business-city" value="myCity" placeholder="Business address" maxlength="15">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-orange" type="submit">Save</button>
```

My vue.js code is

```
var app2 = new Vue({
el: '#mytemplate',
data : {
    message : 'hi',
},
methods: {
    Profile : function () {
        this.message = 'Profile';
    },
    Business : function () {
        // Here I want to call Html Template to load seprate layout
        this.message = 'Business';
    },
    Equipments : function () {
        this.message = 'Equipments';
    }
}
```

})

I have seen lots of answers on the internet but they all using vue template engine or .vue files. Which I do not want to use

Note : I am using CodeIgniter as PHP framework. and Vue for frontend.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to use Vue templates, given that in that case you're left with trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @ChrisG frankly I am new to vueJs and my application is built with CodeIgniter already. Now I want to use vueJs in my application and I just don't know how to mix up both things.

Comment: This is not what Vue was made for. If you want to make a start using Vue inside your existing views, start replacing some existing components on the page with Vue components and let CI do the routing for now.

Comment: @hardik There is no good way to mix the two, since Vue is supposed to deal with the entire frontend and only exchange data with the server. I still don't understand why you do want to use Vue but not as intended? I'm not seeing the upside. If you are new to Vue, why not use it as intended instead of forcing the square peg into the round hole?

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios to render the html. What ever data come in response data variable. That should to show.

```
Profile : function () {
  axios.get('profile.php')
    .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.data);
    // response
    this.message = response.data.json;
   })
    .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
    });
}
```

and to use axios, you have to include cdn file.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```